# Проблема со статикой в django 1.8.3

Tags: django

Пишу проект на *джанго 1.8.3* и есть проблема - не на всех страницах подгружается статика.

Например, есть главная страница `home.html`, которая расширяет `index.html` при помощи тега `extends`. Оба шаблона находятся в директории `banner/templates`, причем `banner` - приложение, которое отвечает за функционал главной страницы. Вся статика находится в файле `projectname/projectname/static`.

В этом случае вся статика отображается ПРАВИЛЬНО.

Но на странице `product_list/id`, шаблон которой находится в `product/templates` (`product` - соответствующее приложение, естественно), и который также начинается с `{% extends index.html %}`, — статика не подгружается и консоль выдает сообщения типа:

> "GET /product_list/1/static/images/skype.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2671.

А в предыдущем случае выдает сообщения типа:

> "GET /static/images/drop_arrow.png HTTP/1.1" 304 0

Насколько я понял, выходит, что в случае главной страницы *джанго* ищет статику в папке `/static/` "главного приложения" (где она и лежит), а в случае `product_list/id` - в папке `/product_list/id/static/`.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какая у этого причина.

```
settings.py:
http://pastie.org/10349278#12-14
```

Вся статика подключается в `index.html` таким образом:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}images/facebook.png" alt="" /></a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое что нужно проверить, это наличие `{% load staticfiles %}` в каждом
шаблоне который использует статичные файлы. Эта строчка не "наследуется" при
наследовании шаблона, она должна быть в каждом файле где-то сверху.

Второе, это то как вы указываете где искать файл. Ваш метод может работать,
но [рекомендованный способ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#static) такой:

```
<img src="{% static 'images/facebook.png' %}" alt="" />
```

---

Ещё лучше брать в кавычки имя родительского шаблона, т.е. `{% extends
'index.html' %}` и если он из другого приложения, то будет `{% extends
'banner/index.html' %}` например.